# Script not executing the condition in devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a template that is being called during one of the stages and it is like below

test-template.yml

```
parameters:
  salary: $(salary)
  location: $(location)
  city: $(city)
  country: $(country)

jobs:
  - job: 
    displayName: 123
    pool: abc
    demands: 
    - OS-ABC

    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: Powershell@2
      displayName: Test
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          write-host "${{parameters.salary}}"
   -  ${{ if eq(parameters.salary, '1234' ) }}:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs: 
        script: |
          write-host "Test Loop"
```

In the above script if loop is not being executed. So I introduced a task above that to validate the parameters.salary and it gives the value '1234'. But, when I am checking the same using an if condition it doesn't go inside the loop.

The value $(salary) is a string and is being passed from another dependent yml file.

I am suspecting that since salary is defined as parameter object it is recognized at the task level and is not recognizing at condition level.

I tried below if conditions

- ${{ if eq('${{ parameters.salary }}', '1234') }}:
- ${{ if eq(parameters['salary'], '1234') }}:

I wanted the script to go inside the if loop.

Comment: Hi @PKP, Have you got a chance to check my answer and test with the suggested workarounds to use runtime expressions in condition or use the variable's static compile time value instead? Kindly also note that the second suggestion doesn't support variables defined in a variable group as such variables are not accessible during compile time either.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$(salary)` is not accessable at the compilation moment. If change your yaml to

```
parameters:
  - name: salary
    default: '1234'
    

jobs:
  - job: 
    displayName: 123

    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: Powershell@2
      displayName: Test
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          write-host "${{parameters.salary}}"
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.salary, '1234' ) }}:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline' 
          script: |
            write-host "Test Loop"
```

You may define your salary here:

[image]

with the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response @Shamrai Aleksander. But the problem here is that the value for salary is being sent as a variable to this template from another template. Therefore I cannot assign a default value  to salary.

Comment: @PKP could you add your `another template` to understand how it was configured?

Answer (score 0):

We can pass [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) value as a parameter into a YAML template. The variable can be passed in runtime expression `$[expression]`/macro syntax `$(variable)`at pipeline [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#run-each-step) or in template expression syntax `${variables.VarName}`at [compile time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline). If we pass the variable value in syntax at runtime, we should not use [conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) (`${if}`) to evaluate the parameter  value at compile time, because in a pipeline, template expressions (`${expressions}`) get processed at compile time, **before** runtime starts.

Taking the sample below for example, during compile time, the variable `mainSalary` is not processed and the parameter `pSalary` value being transferred into template at compile time is the string `$(mainSalary)` rather than its expanded value `1234`. If you are interested, this can be proved if you use the condition `- ${{ if eq(parameters.pSalary, '$(mainSalary)') }}:` instead.

## Pass variable value in macro syntax at runtime

More often the case is we would expect to transfer runtime variable values (like the output variables generated in a script) as parameter into template than to transfer static compile time variable values. For this, we should use [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops) property in runtime expressions for a stage/job/task; to use runtime expression, we need to define variables in the template instead of parameters for evaluation.

###### Main.yml

```
variables:
  mainSalary: 1234
jobs:
- template: TransferParametersTemplate.yml
  parameters:
    pSalary: $(mainSalary) #Pass runtime variable value
```

###### Template.yml

```
parameters:
- name: pSalary
  default: ''
jobs:
- job:
  displayName: 123
  variables:
    templateSalary: ${{ parameters.pSalary }} # Define variable to be evaluated in runtime condition expression
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: Powershell@2
    displayName: Test
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
          Write-Host "${{ parameters.pSalary }}"
  # - ${{ if eq(parameters.pSalary, '1234') }}:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.pSalary, '$(mainSalary)') }}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      condition: eq(variables['templateSalary'], '1234')
      inputs: 
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          write-host "Test Loop"
```

## Pass static variable value in template expression syntax at compile time

Or, you would prefer to pass static compile time variable value, the conditional insertion also works. See the sample below.

###### Main.yml

```
variables:
  mainSalary: 1234
jobs:
- template: TransferParametersTemplate.yml
  parameters:
    pSalary: ${{variables.mainSalary}} #Pass static compile time variable value
```

###### Template.yml

```
parameters:
- name: pSalary
  default: ''
jobs:
- job:
  displayName: 123
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: Powershell@2
    displayName: Test
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
          Write-Host "${{ parameters.pSalary }}"
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.pSalary, '1234') }}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs: 
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          write-host "Test Loop"
```